# restart time after pause

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm trying to do a little countdown in tkinter (python)
i already manage to get this working but when i paused when it starts it starts from the begining.

how can i make the pause button continue the actual time after pause?

thanks

```
    def countdown(self):


    if self.state == True:

        if (self.mins == 0) and (self.secs == 0):
            self.display.config(text="Done!")
            self.state = False
        else:
            self.display.config(text="%02d:%02d" % (self.mins, self.secs))

            if self.secs == 0:
                self.mins -= 1
                self.secs = 59
            else:
                self.secs -= 1

            self.master.after(1000, self.countdown)

def start(self):
    if self.state == False:
        self.state = True
        self.mins = self.minutes
        self.secs = self.seconds
        self.countdown()

def pause(self):
    if self.state == True:
        self.state = False
```

Comment: At `pause(...` update `self.minutes; self.seconds`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, minutes, seconds):
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.seconds = seconds 
        self.state = False
    def countdown(self):
        if self.state == True:
            if (self.mins == 0) and (self.secs == 0):
                print("Done!")
                #self.display.config(text="Done!")
                #self.state = False
            else:
                #self.display.config(text="%02d:%02d" % (self.mins, self.secs))
                if self.secs == 0:
                    self.mins -= 1
                    self.secs = 59
                else:
                    self.secs -= 1
                #self.master.after(1000, self.countdown)
    def start(self):
        if self.state == False:
            self.state = True
            self.mins = self.minutes
            self.secs = self.seconds
            self.countdown()

    def pause(self):
        if self.state == True:
            self.state = False
            #Add these lines into your code#
            self.minutes = self.mins
            self.seconds = self.secs
obj1 = Counter(10,40)
obj1.start()
obj1.pause()
obj1.start()
print(obj1.minutes, obj1.seconds)
```

I modified your code to run on my computer. I added two line in `pause` method.
Edit: Indentation errors are fixed.

Comment: 0


I use that code and it didnt work

your code gives me an error in the first def

and when i put the two lines it wont unpause time

thanks

Comment: You are right, there was indentation error. I fixed it.